# How to import contacts from .vcf file on Samsung device running Android 14?

Tags: samsung, contacts, import, android-14

On my previous generic Chinese Android phone, it was very easy to export/import contacts from a .vcf file.

But on my Samsung running Android 14, I can't find a command to import/export.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Was that on the same device or a different? Please name the phone models you use and have used. Because manufacturer often provide a modified contacts app which extended features like contact im-/export. If you have switches phones this might be the reason you don't find contact import anymore.

Comment: @Robert i get the .vcf file from an old Android Phone , and i want to import in a new Samsung phone with Android 14. The old phone was a generic Chinese phone where i have exported contacts in a .vcf file.

Answer (score 0):

On Samsung devices running Android 14 the Samsung Contact app allows to import and export contacts.

1. Open the left side menu using the three lines (burger menu) button
2. Select the entry "Manage Contacts" (or named similar)
3. A screen appears with multiple buttons, one for Import Contacts and one for Export Contacts.

Answer (score 0):

Click (tap) on the .vcf file, follow the arrows or menu popup to where you want it listed, from the apps displayed. Click the app and it should  go through.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).